# Is there a reusable Dialog for getting a class name in Pharo?

Tags: dialog, smalltalk, pharo

I need something better than writing the entire class name in a text field. Maybe a reduced view of the System Browser.

I've searched class names with 'Dialog' and 'Window' but i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago I've implemented a pluggable completion dialog for OmniBrowser. This is the blog post describing it for end-users:

[OmniBrowser Completion Dialog](http://www.lukas-renggli.ch/blog/ob-completion-dialog)

The model is implemented in `OBCompletionRequest` and the morphic view in `OBCompletionDialog`. While the code currently depends on the OmniBrowser infrastructure, it should be relatively easy to extract. There are no difficult dependencies.

The model is fully pluggable, so the dialog works with any collection of entities. Furthermore, the dialog scales well to huge lists: displaying and filtering all system classes or all system selectors is no big deal.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!